# jQuery: selector question (images)

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm having a HTML document which has images to local files like:

```
<img src="file:///C:/...
```

How can I select all images with file:// in the src tag?

Comment: Ah, the `question` tag.  In case we eventually have some questions that aren't questions...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the [Attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

For example:

```
$('img[src^="file://"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$('img[src^=file:///]')
```

Comment: Until he gets `<img src="file.png" />`.  **EDIT** : This comment is no longer relevant.